# MATLAB Use ! to run a program with a custom path

Tags: matlab, path, directory

I want to run this line of code. It'll run PyMOL on my computer, and $PATH is a variable that holds the current directory of the program being run.

```
 pdbpath = [mfilename('fullpath'), '1AKI.pdb']
 setenv('PATH', pdbpath)
 !//Applications/MacPyMOL.app/Contents/MacOS/MacPyMOL $PATH
```

This doesn't work; `PyMOL` will run but takes the input as $PATH verbatim instead of what `$PATH`  is set to, because ! seems to be a special thing in MATLAB. How do I open programs with customizable paths in MATLAB?

**EDIT**: Also how do I deal with spaces in my path? Since the path is unknown (which is why I'm writing this in the first place) it could have "Program Files" which is bad for command line inputs.

Comment: Try this - `eval(['!//Applications/MacPyMOL.app/Contents/MacOS/MacPyMOL' ' ' getenv('PATH')])`

Comment: Nice, it works - well it does until I hit a file that has a space in its name, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
pdbpath = [mfilename('fullpath'), '1AKI.pdb']
pdbpath = regexprep(pdbpath,' ','\\ '); %%// Replace spaces with slash-spaces
setenv('PATH', pdbpath);
eval(['!//Applications/MacPyMOL.app/Contents/MacOS/MacPyMOL' ' ' getenv('PATH')])
```

Comment: I ended up doing this instead to deal with the spaces.

     pdbpath = ['"', mfilename('fullpath'), 1AKI.pdb', '"']

May be a bit off topic; mfilename('fullpath') gives me the name of the .m file too, whereas I'm looking for 1AKI.pdb in the *same folder*. any ideas on how to cut the file name off the path?

Comment: The above code deals with spaces gracefully. Try FILEPARTS - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html

Comment: @rch: `pth = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))` will give you the full path without the m-filename.

Comment: This might work - `pdbpath = [fileparts(mfilename('fullpath') '/1AKI.pdb']`

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need the `PATH` variable to be an *environment* variable? Usually, there already is one, that you now overwrite....

If not,

```
pdbpath = ['"' fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')), '1AKI.pdb"']
system(['//Applications/MacPyMOL.app/Contents/MacOS/MacPyMOL ' pdbpath]);
```

If yes,

```
setenv('PATH', ['"' fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')), '1AKI.pdb"']);
system(['//Applications/MacPyMOL.app/Contents/MacOS/MacPyMOL ' getenv('PATH')]);
```

Spaces in the path and file name are dealt with in the same way as on the system command line (i.e., it has nothing to do with MATLAB). I put quotation marks in the definition of the `pdbpath` variable, which should do the trick on either Windows, Mac and *nix.

Another option is to escape all spaces (`'\ '`), like Divakar did, but that only works on *nix systems AFAIK, ***and*** only for spaces...There might be other "inconvenient" characters on the path, you know :)

Comment: Ah, I just blindly followed an example on how it worked, probably shouldn't be overwriting something called $PATH... And yeah as I mentioned I did end up going with the quotation marks. Thanks